# C++ const function parameters. Is there a way to declare only single signature of function?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I am working on some project and have problems with duplicating function code. Is there a way to declare only single signature of function which will work for both const and non-const params? Implementation of const and non-const functions are the same.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Data>
struct Processor {

    int process(const Data &data)
    {
        return 42;
    }

    int process(Data &data)
    {
        return 42;
    }

};

int main() {

    using data_type = int;

    data_type non_const_data = 1;
    const data_type const_data = 2;

    std::cout << Processor<data_type>().process(non_const_data) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Processor<data_type>().process(const_data) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Example http://ideone.com/tv0TsF

**THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWERS**

UPDATE

And what about this example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class Container, class Function>
struct Invoker {

    const Container& invoke(const Container &container, Function function)
    {
        for (auto &value : container) function(value);
    }

    Container& invoke(Container &container, Function function)
    {
        for (auto &value : container) function(value);
    }

};

int main() {

    std::vector<int> container {1, 2, 3};
    auto fn = [](int val) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    };

    Invoker<decltype(container), decltype(fn)>().invoke(container, fn);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/KnyGdT

Comment: A better example might be a function that returns a const reference, like [this](http://pastie.org/9398467).

Answer (score 8):

If implementation of both functions are same, then provide `const` parameter function only. It will work both for non-const and const object in your case.

However, if you want to keep the both the function, you can implement non-const parameter function in terms of const parameter function. It will help you to avoid duplicate code.

```
int process(const Data &data)
{
    return 42;
}

int process(Data &data)
{
    return process(static_cast<const Data&>data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please look at my second example in update?

Comment: @Yivo: In this, you cannot get away simply implementing const function. You may need to use const_cast to remove the constness of the return value.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest declaring only the most restrictive one, that being the one that expects a const param. Should there be an issue of sending a non-const pointer/reference into it, you can always make it const before calling the method.

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
int process(const Data &data)
{
    return 42;
}
```

This can be called with `Data`, `Data &`, and `Data const &`, and anything convertible to `Data`.  A const reference can bind to a non-const object or reference.

Comment: It can even bind to a temporary for the duration of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but a similar situation arise in the case of const vs non-const member functions. Sometimes, say for instance in an access function, you would like to have two versions, one usable if the object is const and the other usable when the object is non-const.

```
struct MyString {
   char & at(int index) {
         if (index < size) {
             return data[index];
         else throw std::range_error("Index out of range");
   }

   char at(int index) const {
         if (index < size) {
             return data[index];
         else throw std::range_error("Index out of range");
   }
};
```

Now these functions look very similar, why can't I reuse one to implement the other?

The answer is you *can*, but it requires some very careful casting, first of all the general advice is to call the const-function from the non-const. As you can usually guarantee that calling a const function will be safe even from a non-const context. The call to the const-function will not actually change the object after all. (There are exceptions as with mutable variables, or the reverse of what I'm about to propose just now.)

The solution (according to [More Effective C++](http://books.google.com/books?id=Qx5oyB49poYC)), is use const cast to call the const version from the non-const:

```
   const char & at(int index) const {
         if (index < size) {
             return data[index];
         else throw std::range_error("Index out of range");
   }

   char & at(int index) {
         return const_cast<char &>( static_cast<const MyString>(this)->at(index) );
   }
```

This functions in two steps. First, cast this to a const pointer, that will allow us to invoke the const-version of `at()`. Then, once we return a const-reference to the element, cast it to a writeable reference.